# Adding Style to PHP

Tags: php, css

I have sorted the class thanks. I have also added some text which is a link back to the home page. How would I add css to the "please click here to return to the home page"

```
<?php
        if  (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {
        echo '<div class="thanks"><p>Thanks for contacting us!</div></p>' , '<a href ="index.html">please click here to return to the home page</a>';

} else {


    if (empty($errors)=== false){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: give your `ul` a class and target that?

Comment: you can directly add class in your <ul> tag like: '<ul class="your class">'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
                if  (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {
        echo '<div class="abc1"><p>Thanks for contacting us!</p></div>';

} else {



if (empty($errors)=== false){
    echo '<ul class="abc">';
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use one of those two options:

**1. Create your own CSS file with something like this:**

```
.yourClass{
         color: red;
         background-color: cyan;
        }
```

And then when creating the element inside your PHP add this:

```
echo '<p class="yourClass">Thanks for contacting us!</p>';
```

**2. In this case you would directly add your styles inside PHP:**

```
echo '<p style="background-color:cyan; color:red;">Thanks for contacting us!</p>';
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have it sorted now thanks.

```
'<a href ="index.html"><div class="click"><p>please click here to return to the home page</div></p></a>';
```